# What does it mean "a" and " the" before " Billion " in these sentences?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I have read two examples about "Billion" word and I got confused with why are existences "a" and " the" in these contexts . Is it mentioned "definite" and "indefinite" meaing ?

Examples- 
1. The Clinton administration last winter assembled **the** $50 billion emergency bailout package to ease a financial crisis in Mexico.( From Cambridge dictionary )

2. It is estimated that UK business could save **a** further $3 billion if they made the effort. (From my book)

Answer (score 2):

The articles "a" and "the" don't actually attach to "billion".

In the first example, "the" attaches to "bailout package", which is further modified by specifying its size as "$50 billion".

The second example should be read as "a further 30 billion dollars", and that is an elliptical way of saying "an additional sum of 30 billion dollars."

Comment: There's no weird rule in English that would prescribe reading "3 billion" as "30 billion".

Comment: My, what a cogent observation.

Comment: And yet your answer still advises interpreting the sentence with a number 10 times larger than what's printed.  Once you make the edit we can clean up these comments.